# Use Generic class with SqlDataReader GetValue

Tags: c#, generics, sqldatareader

I have this code that works ok with a database with no NULL values

```
public T GetField<T>(SqlDataReader dr, string fieldName)
{
    return (T)dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldName));
}
```

Then I want to control the DBNull values, because they already exist in some tables and I upgraded the function like this:

```
public T GetField<T>(SqlDataReader dr, string fieldName) where T : new()
{
    var value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldName));   
    return value is DBNull ? new T() : (T)value;
}
```

But now, I cannot ask for `GetField<string>` because string has no constructor with 0 parameters.

I have tried to create another function like the Abstract one, with no restrictions and only with string type like this

```
public string GetField<string>(SqlDataReader dr, string fieldName)
{
    var value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldName));   
    return value is DBNull ? "" : value.ToString();
}
```

but the answer is that they are ambiguous definitions, because T also includes string, even with the restriction applied.

I could create independent functions for each datatype, but I rather prefer the abstract solution because it is way much cleaner.

Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "another function like the abstract one" - which abstract what? You haven't shown any abstract methods or classes... did you mean generic? (Generic and abstract mean very different things in C#.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant Generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
public T GetField<T>(SqlDataReader dr, string fieldName)
{
    var value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldName));
    return value is DBNull ? default(T) : (T) value;
}
```

This has the added benefit of working with nullable types. Then you'd call that as:

```
string x = foo.GetField<string>(reader, "field") ?? "";
```

Which is deliberately contrived in this case -- Jon's version with a default suits you better if usually you want something other than `null` returned.

Comment: That was exactly was I was looking for. Mixing both solutions give me the flexibility to answer all my scenarios. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your final method would fail because it's trying to declare a type parameter called `string`.

I suggest you add another overload without the constraint on `T`, but with a default value:

```
public T GetField<T>(SqlDataReader dr, string fieldName, T defaultValue)
{
    var value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldName));   
    return value is DBNull ? defaultValue : (T) value;
}
```

Then you'd call it as:

```
string x = foo.GetField(reader, "field", "");
```

... with the added benefit that the method isn't string-specific.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yup, fixed.

Comment: The default value is a nice feature to have and I have included it, thanks!